# Javascript output issue with setTimeout and IIFI

Tags: javascript

I am running

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }(i), 4000);
}
```

Above code not waiting for 4 sec, it instantly prints 0, 1, 2.

Can somebody explain the reason for this output?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you're immediately executing your callback. If anything, your IIFE needs to *return another function*.

Comment: In more words: `function () { console.log(i); }` is a function which, when called, will log the value of `i`. And you're immediately calling this function. If anything, you want this function to be a function which, when called, *returns another function which, when called, logs the value of `i`.* See the duplicate for many examples of that.